# How is the damage multiplier for Bag of Orange Pegs determined?

Tags: peglin

The description for the relic Bag of Orange Pegs says

> Attacks get an increasing damage multiplier based on the number of (peg slots)

The [Peglin wiki says](https://peglin.fandom.com/wiki/Bag_of_Orange_Pegs) the multiplier increases the more popped pegs are on the board in relation to how many pegs there were to start with, and that the multiplier can go up to 4x.

How does the damage multiplier scale with the number of popped pegs? IE: If half the pegs on the board are popped, would the damage multiplier be 2x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From counting pegs and the [from the Developer themself](https://old.reddit.com/r/Peglin/comments/184nj4n/okay_i_just_cant_seem_to_figure_it_out/kb0t428/):

- For 100% to 60% pegs remain: x1 Damage
- For 60% to 30% pegs remain: x2 Damage
- For 30% to 10% pegs remain: x3 Damage
- For 10% to 1% pegs remain: x4 Damage
- For less than 1% pegs remain: x10 Damage

Comment: For anyone reading this, feel free to update the Fandom Wiki if you like.

Comment: That link goes back to this question page.

Comment: whoops my bad, seems like my clipboard didn't update first time I copy pasted. Fixed now.